# convert PDF to EPS to PNG without text

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

How to convert PDF to PNG (and filter out the text)..

I want to render images and vector graphics (vector text included) without plain text

Below only the image is extracted.. not the whole page of the PDF

```
gs -sDEVICE=eps2write -dFILTERTEXT -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -o out.eps 091.pdf
convert -density 300 -background white -alpha off out.eps -resize 2480x3508! OUT.png
```

## from EPS

[image]

## PDF

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FILTERTEST switch (as I'm pretty sure is documented) only works on **text**, not on image which contain a pattern of pixels which look like text, or on vector linework which looks like text.

Wihtout seeing your EPS I can't tell if the text you are complaining about is text or not, but my guess would be not.

By the way, if you want a PNG then there's no reason to convert the EPS to PDF, just render the EPS directly to a PNG file.

Comment: IMO imagemagick do the best rendering so thats why :) I just want to render all images and text (vector) without the plain text.. here is the original PDF https://docdro.id/6nHuhuJ

Comment: I checked the content of the PDF file, the gray ellipse is an image, and so is the 'text' inside it. Since the text is image pixels, not text, the FILTERTEXT switch can't do anything about it. As I said above IM uses GS to render both EPS files and PDF files, so there really is no point in converting the PDF to EPS. In fact, there's a good reason not to; PostScript's imaging model doesn't support transparency, so any pages with transparency will be rendered to an image. So you're losing fidelity and the FILTER* siwtches won't work as well as they would with the original PDF.

Comment: So do you have a solution to get a PNG only with images and vector text (without plain text)?

Comment: I have splittested and IM does to a better job when rendering vector text

Comment: And I already handle PDF's with transparency with another method.. :) I just need to get a PNG with the full page and not just the image

Comment: Unless you are doing something special, IM is using Ghostscript to render the PDF file. It may well be doing some post-processing, but you could do that yourself too. I'm confused what it is you are asking for. I thought you wanted just the image, it seems like that's what you are getting, all the text has been removed. Note that if you are converting to an **EPS**, then the Bounding Box will be set to the marking objects on the page. If you want the original media size then you need to convert to **PostScript**, not Encapsulated PostScript.

Comment: Or, as I said, just render to PNG directly from Ghostscript.

Comment: I will just juse GS for the whole chain